# a simple question about probabilities

Tags: probability

In a game a player has a probability of $
\frac{1}
{N} 
$  to win, where $
N \in {\Bbb N}
$. It´s possible to calculate the probability of at least one win, after $k$ tries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the probability of at least one win is 1 minus the probability of no wins: $1-\bigl(1-{1\over N}\bigr)^k$
(assuming independence between games).

In general, you use $P(A)=1-P(\text{not }A)$.  The complement of (the "not" of)    "at least one" is "none".

Comment: Trying again N times, what is the probability of at least "j" wins D:? I can´t do the same here or yes :S?